Spring Cloud OpenFeign is not sending audio/ogg header when calling the endpoint
I'm trying to send audio OGG file bytes via Spring Cloud Feign Client by calling the API.
But I'm getting a 400 Bad Request with the error given below:
"error_message" : "OGG header has not been found"

Although, if the OGG file was sent from Postman (with the same headers and OGG file), then everything works just fine.
FeignClient:
@FeignClient(name = "${integration[0].speech.name}",
        url = "${integration[0].speech.url}",
        configuration = SpeechRecognizerConfig.class)
public interface YandexSpeechRecognizerClient {

    @PostMapping
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type", "audio/ogg"
    })
    RecognizedTextResponse recognizeText(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,
                                         @RequestParam("lang") String lang,
                                         @RequestBody ByteArrayResource oggFileBytes);

}

FeignClient config:
@Bean
public Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return Logger.Level.FULL;
}

@Bean
public Client httpFeignClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient(new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .build());
}

@Bean
public Feign.Builder speechFeignBuilder(@Autowired Logger.Level logLevel, @Autowired Client client) {
    return Feign.builder()
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(log))
            .logLevel(logLevel)
            .client(client);
}

Test method:
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(oggFile.toPath());
RecognizedTextResponse yandexRecognizedTextResponse = underTest.recognizeText(
                "Bearer " + authClient.getToken().getAccessToken(),
                "en-EN",
                false,
                false,
                "123123123",
                new ByteArrayResource(bytes)
        );

I have tried every other alternatives but none of them are working.
How to fix this issue?

@AnishB. Sample codebase? What do you mean?

@AnishB. Code above? What do you want to test?

@Header annotation on Feign client method seems not to work as expected. You can try to inject static header that way:
@PostMapping(headers = "content-type=audio/ogg")
// or
@PostMapping(produces = "audio/ogg")

Another options would be to use RequestInterceptor in dedicated FeignClientConfig:
@Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> 
            requestTemplate.header("Content-Type", "audio/ogg");
    }

or specify default headers in configuration properties as follows:
feign:
  client:
    config:
      your-client-name:
        Content-Type:
          - audio/ogg

But the downside of these two approaches is that they would impact other methods of same feign client
